# pass variable to javabean

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have a `register.jsp` file. It reads the variable from a form submitted as follows:

```
    <%
        if(request.getParameter("username") != null && request.getParameter("password") != null){
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
         }
     %>
```

I have a java bean as follows.

```
public class RegistrationBean {


// Constructor
public RegistrationBean(){}  


public boolean login(String username, String password){
    boolean result = false;
    System.out.println("username");
    if(username.equals("username") && password.equals("admin")){
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}


}
```

Now I am trying to call this login function in my jsp file as follows. I added the useBean at the top of my jsp file as well.

```
    <jsp:useBean id="register" class="registration.RegistrationBean" scope="session" />

    <%
        if(request.getParameter("username") != null && request.getParameter("password") != null){
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            if(register.login(username, password)){
              // do something
            }
     %>
```

But I realised that The value of username and password isn't being passed to the bean. But when I print the value in .jsp file it had the appropriate value. Is there any reason why the value isn't being passed to the function in the login() function. At the momen its false no matter what I do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should actually work.
However, this is an alternate way of getting it to work:

```
<jsp:useBean id="register" class="registration.RegistrationBean" scope="session">
<jsp:setProperty name="register" property="username" value="<%=request.getParameter("username")%>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="register" property="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
<jsp:useBean />
```

Add setters and getters for `username` and `password` in your `RegistrationBean` class. `username` and `password` will be class variables. Make `login` function as non-parameterized i.e. call it as `register.login()`.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute value request.getParameter("sn") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value

above message is occur when i am running my page using value="<%=request.getParameter("val")%>"/>

Comment: i got the awnser      u can use script to make the use of it |||||take a <% String s=request.getparameter("var"); %>    and then use the string s to the jsp:use bean value tag like value="s" nd then u get what u want